# Consume ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net

Have to consume a web API. The Controller looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;
using ERPService.Api.Models;
using ERPService.Core.Services;

namespace ERPService.Api.Controllers
{

    [RoutePrefix("api/local")]
    public class LocalProductController : BaseApiController
    {
        [Route("product/{productId}/export")]
        public ApiResponse<IList<ServiceResponse<object>>> ExportProduct(int productId)
        {
            return Response(this.ServiceFactory.ProductService.ExportProduct(productId));
        }

    }
}
```

Using HttpClient how can I call that ExportProduct function?
I created a console application to consume this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:49319/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/local/product/{productId}/export").Result;
```

The result is an error as following:

Error Code - MethodNotAllowed

Message - Method Not Allowed

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: You use the HttpClient to load the route associated with the method.  What have you tried?

Comment: try it like this:
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:49319/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/local/product/{productId}/export").Result;

It is clear for me that I can't use Get but what should I use?

Comment: What makes you think you can't use Get?  (PS- you should edit your question to add the relevant code that is not working and any errors that you receive)

Comment: With the above code I'm getting: Error Code MethodNotAllowed : Message - Method Not Allowed

Comment: You use the HttpClient

Answer (score 0):

```
string json;
        WebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        req.Method = "GET";
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {

                    json = responseReader.ReadToEnd();

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for the problem: had to add the [HttpGet] attribute so it should look like this:

```
[Route("product/{productId}/export")]
[HttpGet]
public ApiResponse<IList<ServiceResponse<object>>> ExportProduct(int productId)
{
  return Response(this.ServiceFactory.ProductService.ExportProduct(productId));
}
```